# Disabling session cookie for part of the application

Tags: spring-security

I have a web application that is secured using Spring Security. Part of the application is exposed as REST services. Every thing is working as expected.

I am handling the authentication using a Custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. So sessions are not required for me.  I noticed that my REST calls are sending `Set-Cookie:` headers. How do I disable them only for part of my web application.